# Envio de form para Pagseguro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formulário

Tenho este form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PacoteAdd", "Pacote"))
        {
        <input type="hidden" name="email_cobranca" value="*****@hotmail.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="CBR" />
        <input type="hidden" name="moeda" value="BRL" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="@item.PacoteID" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_descr" value="@item.Titulo" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_quant" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_valor" value="@item.valor" />
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/99x61-comprar-assina.gif"
        alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!" />
}
```

e este código no controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void PacoteAdd(FormCollection fomr)
{
     string email_cobranca = Request.Form["email_cobranca"];
     string tipo = Request.Form["tipo"];
     string moeda = Request.Form["moeda"];
     string item_id = Request.Form["item_id"];
     string item_descr = Request.Form["item_descr"];
     string item_quant = Request.Form["item_quant"];
     string item_valor = Request.Form["item_valor"];
}
```

e precisaria enviar este form no link

> https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/checkout.jhtml

pois o código original do botão seria este abaixo

```
<form target="pagseguro" method="post" action="https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/checkout.jhtml">
      <input type="hidden" name="email_cobranca" value="*****@hotmail.com" />
      <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="CBR" />
      <input type="hidden" name="moeda" value="BRL" />
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="@item.PacoteID" />
      <input type="hidden" name="item_descr" value="@item.Titulo" />
      <input type="hidden" name="item_quant" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="item_valor" value="@item.valor" />
      <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/99x61-comprar-assina.gif" alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!" />
</form>
```

o que deveria usar para enviar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só incluir a url externa no `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@action="https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/checkout.jhtml"}
)
{
... aqui vão os inputs e botão submit
}
```

Para postar dados a partir da controller você pode usar o `HttpClient`:

```
var parametros = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
parametros.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email_cobranc", "*****@hotmail.com"));
// Adicionar os outros parâmetros

var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(parametros);
var cliente = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br") };

var response = cliente.PostAsync("/checkout/checkout.jhtml", content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // aqui você trata o retorno
}
```

Você pode precisar adicionar uma linha para evitar erros de certificado, uma vez que o seu link é `https`.

Comment: eu preciso que o form seja enviado do controller, pois preciso executar uma ação no controller antes de enviar o form.

Comment: veja a resposta, editei com em exemplo de como você pode fazer a requisição na controller